# Microsoft Outlook Address book's title is not displayed properly

Tags: visual-c++, outlook, window, mapi

I'm developing an application from which I want to send EMail. When I click button/menu Outlook Sendmail window displays properly.

When I open Address Book, the dialog displays properly but the title of the dialog dispalys only "S".

Actually that title has to be displayed as " Selected Names: ... ".

Code:

```
HWND hWnd = this->GetSafeHwnd();
MAPIINIT_0 tMapInit = { 0, MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATIONS };
HRESULT hResult = MAPIInitialize( &tMapInit );
HMODULE hMapiMod = LoadLibrary(_T("mapi32.dll"));

ProcMapiLogon = (LPMAPILOGON)GetProcAddress( hMapiMod, "MAPILogon" );

(ProcMapiLogon)( (ULONG)hWnd, NULL, NULL, MAPI_LOGON_UI | MAPI_NEW_SESSION, 0, &hCurrentSession );


LPMAPISENDMAIL ProcMapiSendMail = NULL;
ProcMapiSendMail = (LPMAPISENDMAIL)GetProcAddress(hMapiMod, "MAPISendMail");
(ProcMapiSendMail)(hCurrentSession, (ULONG)hWnd, &myMsg, MAPI_DIALOG | MAPI_LOGON_UI, 0);
```

Note: This applicaion is build in command prompt with unicode flag _UNICODE set and the compiler is Visual Studio 2008.

Kindly help me to fix the problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple MAPI functions only work with ANSI strings. Also keep in mind that it is never a good idea to rely on conditional compile when interfacing with Simple or Extended MAPI. Always specify the string flavor (ANSI vs wide string) explicitly in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I creaed one test application for testing purpose and I build it in Visual Studio 2008 with Character Set as "Use Unicode Character Set" in project settings. 

This displays title name of the "Address Book" properly (Selected Names: Global Address List).

What would be the difference for this setting and conditional compile with _UNICODE setting.

Is there any other way to display the title of the "Address Book" dialog properly?

Thanks in advance.